# Middleware for handling birthdays in Clean Architecture .net Core API

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, middleware, clean-architecture

I have a .net core API using Clean Architecture.

There is a main branch of the project with minimal features, however, depending on our clients some of them will want some optional features, lets say: show students birthday when fetching the students endpoint.

So we want this feature not to interfere with the main branch and keep some isolation in terms of the way we organize the code, so compiling for a client that does not need this feature is as simple as removing a line.

Im thinking of using custom middlewares for this cases. But is it a good practice and how should it interact with the other layers?

Thanks

Comment: I personaly think using a middleware is not a good idea. It would need to query the database a second time just to get an extra column and then adding it to the object. I would rather work with a boolean parameter (include_bday) or even have a second route.

Comment: Thanks @meq the birthday example is just one case, there might be multiple "modules" that can be added or removed depending on the client we are compiling for. We have a second table with student metadata with key value columns, for any information required by the optional module

Comment: What you're looking for is essentially a feature toggle. There's many different libraries and solutions for this; you just need to pick one or build your own if you prefer. It boils down to basically wrapping the code that can vary in some "feature", and then via config, you either enable or disable this feature on a per client basis.

Comment: I just checked feature toggle, but what I want is a clean way to separate the "addons" code but still preserving the clean architecture layers so that an addon can access the db service but also perform other actions that should be in other layers